# I get "Error: Please install `npm` before continuing" when putting in the command: 'vercel' into VS code terminal

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, npm, terminal, vercel

Im a absolute newbie to VS code and react: Im doing the "wesbos - react for beginners" course and am at the stage of deployment.

TL;DR: I am a beginenr: I get Error: Please install `npm` before continuing in vs code for react course project and ChatGPT's solutions arent' helping/nor I am getting solutions. I use the most up to date npm and node.js downloaded from Node.js website.

ChatGPT isnt much help with - Error: Please install `npm` before continuing.

- I have tried to 2 versions of npm that I got from the Node.js website. Current versions are npm: 10.2.5, and node: v20.10.0
- GPT said to check file path, I did and everything was there as it describe it should be.
- the 'now' command I don't use any more (i think its to do with scripts under the package.json file can't say with certainty, I dont have much clue haha) and now use the command 'vercel'
- this then says
  vercel CLI 33.1.0 followed by
  "Inspect: Https:// ......" link, under that is
  "Preview: https:// ...... " link
- followed by  "Error: please instal `npm` before continuing.
- ADDITIONALLY: I dont know if i have linked things correctly between github and vercel etc and what everelse that needs to be used for things to work. Its quite overwhelming.

Sorry about the long post, really, I know next to nothing and its the best way i could describe as of now. (I dislike how the guy teaches and skips over too many things IMO for a 'beginners' course, but Im almost done so..).

Also, this query could be trivial in some eyes and theres actually some documentations I have yet to know of please let me know too.

Thanks

- I tried 2 different versions of npm and node.js, an older one around node 16.0.0 (maybe? I cant recall) both downloaded from NOde.js website. I expected that a uptodate versions would solve my issue.
- I tried talking to ChatGPT 4 about this and all its solutions such as checking its path location or uninstall/reinstall node, npm etc, none worked and its end response was my issue is unique ...  and doesnt suggest much more than that. I expected GPT to tell me where I went wrong (not that the expectation is huge or anything).
- Looked for doumentations pertaining to vercel, node js, npm, stack overflow, counld'nt find anything relevant (atleast what I think)

Comment: Well, stupid question before continuing: Do you have npm installed? Then: What exactly were you doing to produce the error message? Is the npm executable found into the [PATH](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable) of the process (most likely some shell) which produces the error?

Comment: This is possibly a recent change. I had a working vercel PHP deployment until the end of last year (just a static site). Suddenly no longer works, asking for an NPM install. Vercel.json is a tricky thing to configure (still haven't found a solution)